# NoMethodError in Admin::Posts#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am attempting to add content into the Show page including the title, content and publish details. When I run this from my local host I receive the following error;

```
Showing /Users/laurenwoodhams/Desktop/PROJECT/RAILS-BLOG/-t/app/views/admin/posts/show.html.erb where line #2 raised:

undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass
<h1>Admin::Posts#show</h1>
<p><b>title:</b> <%= @post.title %></p>
<p><b>content:</b> <%= @post.content %></p>
<p><b>publish:</b> <%= @post.publish %></p>
<p><b>created:</b> <%= @post.created_at %></p>
```

This is the appearance of my Show form in sublime;

```
<h1>Admin::Posts#show</h1>
<p><b>title:</b> <%= @post.title %></p>
<p><b>content:</b> <%= @post.content %></p>
<p><b>publish:</b> <%= @post.publish %></p>
<p><b>created:</b> <%= @post.created_at %></p>
```

Post Controller;

```
class Admin::PostsController < Admin::ApplicationController
  def index
    if params[:search].present?
      @posts = Post.matching_title_or_content(params[:search]).page params[:page]
    else
      @posts = Post.all.order(id: :desc).page params[:page]
    end
  end

  def new
  end

  def create
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
  end

  def show
    @posts = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
  end
end
```

Could you please explain why this error is occurring?

Comment: All this is saying is that `@post` is `nil`. Did you initialize it in the controller?

Comment: Please show your PostsController so we can help you.

Comment: @SacWebDeveloper. Apologies, I have amended this in my post for you to view now.

Comment: @ndn, I have amended now, please see amended question.

Comment: @LaurenW - rename `@posts` to `@post` in your show action.

Comment: @BroiSatse, Thank you. This worked!

Answer (score 0):

Your view uses `@post` variable but in your show action you define `@posts`. May be a typo. Try:

```
def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For **index** method

```
  def index
    if params[:search].present?
      @posts = Post.matching_title_or_content(params[:search]).page params[:page]
    else
      @posts = Post.all.order(id: :desc).page params[:page]
    end
  end
```

for **show** method

```
  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end
```